# Trying to change WixLib preprocessor variable in referenced solution

Tags: wix, wix3.6, wixlib

I created a WixLib project and solution that contains a fragment that points to a set of DLLS's I would like to include in multiple projects.

However when I reference this wixlib from other solutions the preprocessor value for the directory the dlls are in come with the wixlib.  I would like to override this value or update it.

My Wixlib looks like this:

```
<Fragment>
   <ComponentGroup Id="CG.FarPointComponents">
      <Component Id="cmpBBC3777DD58F5E2AE4704D66EF87C105" Directory="INSTALLDIR"
                 Guid="6CB60019-D122-41F6-8009-C41B07BCE5C3">
         <File Id="filC126C8C2BFE502E045C17A812B8A907D" KeyPath="yes"
               Source="$(var.FarPointDir)\FarPoint.CalcEngine.dll" />
      </Component>
   </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

I want to specify another directory for the var.FarPointDir in the other solution what should I do? I am using wix 3.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few options:

1. Create a `binary .wixlib` - use the `-bf` switch to `lit.exe` to embed the files into the .wixlib. That way the .wixlib is completely self-contained, although it will be bigger.
2. Use `bind paths` - bind paths are like search paths but to find the files that need to end up in the package. If you make the `File/@Source` relative (do not start with `X:\` or just `\`) then the unnamed bind paths will be searched. You specify bind paths to `light.exe` using the `-bp` command-line switch. Alternatively you can use named bind paths, they look like this:

   ```
   <File Source='!(bindpath.Name)\FarPoint.CalcEngine.dll' />
   ```

   Again, the `-bp` switch can create named bind paths.
3. Use `bind variable` - instead of using a preprocessor variable (resolved before "compile"), use a variable that is resolved at "bind time". You can reference a bind variable like: `!(wix.Var)`. That can be set on the command-line to `light.exe` or you can set it in code using the `WixVariable` element.

I use option #1 to distribute .wixlibs to other people (to be self-contained), and option #2 if it's just my stuff (binary .wixlibs will slow the build a bit).

Comment: do you have an idea on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59358963/wix-serviceinstall-service-referencing-a-exe-from-wixlib